# Recyclerview crashes when removing last item. NullPointerException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()

Tags: android, null, crash, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview, that is populated using an arraylist. When I remove an item from the list, it works fine, until the last item gets removed. Below is the code found in my recyclerview adapter, that removes an item.

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
        itemsData.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Below here is the crash log. The log doesn't direct me to a specified place in my code. So I'm not sure whats causing the problem.

I did some testing and logged the position. If I add an item into the arraylist and `notifyItemInserted` in the recyclerview the position of the item added, is 0. If I click on the added item, the position is 0 and if I remove the item I remove it at position 0, yet it crashed when removing the item as position 0.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
>               at android.support.v7.widget.OrientationHelper$2.getDecoratedStart(OrientationHelper.java:316)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findOneVisibleChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:1633)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleChildClosestToStart(LinearLayoutManager.java:1453)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.computeScrollOffset(LinearLayoutManager.java:997)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.computeVerticalScrollOffset(LinearLayoutManager.java:969)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.java:1175)
>               at android.view.View.canScrollVertically(View.java:12835)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS.canScrollVertically(ViewCompatICS.java:35)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$ICSViewCompatImpl.canScrollVertically(ViewCompat.java:1136)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(ViewCompat.java:1528)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerView.java:6594)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerView.java:6573)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(LinearLayoutManager.java:204)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:66)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:228)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:56)
>               at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5439)
>               at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5312)
>               at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:20823)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:117)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:210)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:358)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:255)
>               at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:82)
>               at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5297)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6934)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.runOrPost(ViewRootImpl.java:6960)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.postSendWindowContentChangedCallback(ViewRootImpl.java:6161)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewRootImpl.java:6274)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:2772)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(

Any help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: do you find any solution? i have the same problem when using `notifyItemRemoved`, BUT there is no problem when using `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: No. Sadly I did not :( Sorry ma'am/sir

Answer (score -1):

Put a check for "not null" and it should be fine. Something like this :

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
       if(itemsData != null){
        itemsData.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
       }
}
```

Hope this helps.